# How can I quickly switch between different line widths / print margins in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working in a codebase where there are two different code styles for Java files that I have to maintain. It is a pain to open up preferences and switch the profile each time I change a file.

Some files have an 80 character width whereas other files have 100. I cannot easily separate the different files into different projects.

Comment: You may use two workspaces, each with its own configuration.

Comment: Both type of these files belongs to the same projects or different projects?Having different `Formatting profile` for the files belonging to a single project is **Bad practice**

Comment: As I stated in the question, both types of files are in the same project and I cannot easily separate them. I know it is bad practice, but doing a large-scale refactoring is not a short-term option.